# How to detect the reselection of same pyqt combobox element

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I have a pyqtgraph Combobox which is defined as follows.

```
def __init__(self):
    # some other stuff....

    mylist=OrderedDict()
    mylist['1k'] = 1
    mylist['10k'] = 10
    mylist['100k'] = 100
    mylist['1M'] = 1000
    self.myselectorA = ComboBox()
    self.myselectorA.setItems(mylist)
    self.myselectorA.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.selchangedA)

def selchangedA(self):
    self.sq.setA(self.myselectorA.value())
    if self.sq.gainlink:
        self.sq.setB(100./self.myselectorA.value())
        self.viewupdate = True
        self.myselectorB.setValue(100./self.myselectorA.value())
        self.viewupdate = False
```

The attached callback function `selchangedA` does some stuff which includes the optional update of a second Combobox (`myselectorB`). This update is dependant on a further variable `gainlink`.

I have the situation where I need to be able to detect the reselection of the same element in the combobox so that it updates the secondary combobox. Is this possible?

I understand that the user should just select the appropriate value on the secondary combobox but I want maximum flexibility for the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `currentIndexChanged(int)` you can connect the signal `activated(int)` (which is also emitted if the choice didn't change but an element was selected) to `selchangedA(self, int)`. Besides that you can save the current index of the combo box in a separate variable and check in `selchangedA` if the value is the same as the previous and act accordingly.

Comment: Perfect, just what I want! Thanks. I didn't use the `int` functionality because I want the OrderedDict value rather than the index of the selection.  Thanks again!